# No access to web or mysql on vagrant after upgrading to macos monterey

Tags: vagrant, macos-monterey

Last week I decided to upgrade the mac to the latest version Monterey. Well. Most things works, except for Vagrant. Well.. it works, except there is almost no connection to the server.

vagrant ssh works.

I have been able to launch virtualbox, but access to http or mysql is not happening.
I know the mysql-server is running. The same goes with the apache server.

Logs have been checked and I cannot see that any traffic going to the server.

Ping is not working.

I have updated virtualbox. I have destroyed the box and upgraded vagrant / homestead. still no luck.

MORE INFO:

When I run traceroute I see that the first hit is the correct IP I have set in hosts file. Then it goes to 192.168.0.1 which isn't going anywhere.

I guess the 192.168.0.1 comes from the mac virtualbox / vagrant is running on.

Any pointers on what to do next are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same problem as mine (I couldn't use any longer IP 192.168.10.10). VirtualBox did some changes lately (from VirtualBox 6.1.28 I think) and a new configuration is needed to use your preferred  (192.168.0.1) IP address:

> On Linux, macOS and Solaris Oracle VM VirtualBox will only allow IP
> addresses in 192.168.56.0/21 range to be assigned to host-only
> adapters. For IPv6 only link-local addresses are allowed. If other
> ranges are desired, they can be enabled by creating
> /etc/vbox/networks.conf and specifying allowed ranges there. For
> example, to allow 10.0.0.0/8 and 192.168.0.0/16 IPv4 ranges as well as
> 2001::/64 range put the following lines into /etc/vbox/networks.conf:
>
> ```
>   * 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16
>   * 2001::/64
> ```

You can check the whole information [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly).

Alternatively (skipping the `networks.conf` configuration) you can use any IP from the initially supported range like for instance: 192.168.56.10